# Finding the position vector from the velocity vector?

Tags: calculus

A block moves outward along the slot in the platform with a speed of $\frac{dr}{dt}=4t$ m/s, where t is in seconds.  If the block starts from rest from half the distance of the platform, determine the slots position with respect to time.

My attempt:

$$\int_0^t 4t\,dt=\int_{\frac{r}{2}}^r \,dr \implies 2t^2=\frac{1}{2}r \implies r=4t^2$$

Is this correct? I am not sure if my integration bounds are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r = 2t^2 + d_o$, with $d_0$ is the initial position which is half the distance from the platform. To see why this is true, note that $r(t) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^t r'(t)dt + r(0) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^t 4tdt + d_0 = 2t^2 + d_0$.